# With AWS SageMaker, is it possible to deploy a pre-trained model using the sagemaker SDK?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to avoid migrating an existing model training process to SageMaker and avoid creating a custom Docker container to host our trained model.

My hope was to inject our existing, trained model into the pre-built scikit learn container that AWS provides via the [sagemaker-python-sdk](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sagemaker.sklearn.html#scikit-learn-estimator). All of the examples that I have found require training the model first which creates the model/model configuration in SageMaker. This is then deployed with the `deploy` method.

Is it possible to provide a trained model to the `deploy` method and have it hosted in the pre-built scikit learn container that AWS provides?

For reference, [the examples](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_iris/Scikit-learn%20Estimator%20Example%20With%20Batch%20Transform.ipynb) I've seen follow this order of operations:

1. Creating an instance of `sagemaker.sklearn.estimator.SKLearn` and providing a training script
2. Call the `fit` method on it
3. This creates the model/model configuration in SageMaker
4. Call the `deploy` method on the `SKLearn` instance which automagically takes the model created in step 2/3 and deploys it in the pre-build scikit learn container as an HTTPS endpoint.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can import existing models to SageMaker.

For scikit-learn, you would use the SKLearnModel() object to load to model from S3 and create it in SageMaker. Then, you could deploy it as usual.

https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker.sklearn.html

Here's a full example based on MXNet that will point you in the right direction:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/mxnet_onnx_superresolution/mxnet_onnx.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with the same use case for a couple days.

We used sagemaker.model.Model class and sagemaker.pipeline.PipelineModel

Outlined our solution here.

[How to handle custom transformation/ inference and requirements in sagemaker endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70311093/how-to-handle-custom-transformation-inference-and-requirements-in-sagemaker-end)

Comment: Any updated links - this page doesn't exist anymore.