# How to store a .tar.gz formatted model to AWS SageMaker and use it as a deployed model?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, deployment, amazon-sagemaker, bert-language-model

I have a pre-trained BERT model which was trained on Google Cloud Platform, and the model is stored in a .tar.gz formatted file, I wanted to deploy this model to SageMaker and also be able to trigger the model via API, how can I achieve this?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54916866/with-aws-sagemaker-is-it-possible-to-deploy-a-pre-trained-model-using-the-sagem) is a little bit related to what I'm asking here, but it's for a scikit-learn model, I'm new to this area, can someone give me some guidance regarding this? Many thanks.

Comment: This question is hard to answer because we do not know the framework the model was trained in (Tensorflow or Pytorch) and we do not know which framework you want to load it in (Tensorflow or Pytorch)

Comment: @CoreyLevinson Hi Both are Tensorflow

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it just from Tensorflow Hub? There is a library Tensorflow Hub that allows you to load the model just using a URL.

Comment: Oh could you share the link with me please? You meant using a URL to deploy it to SageMaker?

Comment: Sure, as long as your sagemaker can connect to the internet. You can follow the steps here: https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/3

By the way, for NLP I strongly recommend using Huggingface Transformers I think it's a lot easier.

Comment: this page didn't mention anything about SageMaker, I think you probably missed my point in my original question, I still want to deploy to SageMaker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224898/discussion-between-corey-levinson-and-cecilia).

Answer (score 1):

To use an existing model object this just needs to be packaged in a .tar.gz and stored in S3.

Once that is packaged then you can deploy it using the sage maker API through sage maker notebooks \studio or terraform.

### Packaging the code

#### File Structure

Here is the structure of what the .tar.gz should follow.

```
|----- preprocessing.joblib # multiple model objects included here
|----- model.joblib
|----- code
    |----- inference.py # used for custom transformation \ loading model etc. 
    |----- requirements.txt # can be ran to include dependencies not in the docker image
```

#### Zipping your files

ex.

```
tar czvf model.tar.gz. model_xgb.joblib preprocessor.joblib code
```

### Deploying Endpoint

Once you have the model packaged then you can create an endpoint by loading the model into one of the model classes and then deploying it.

```
from sagemaker.amazon.amazon_estimator import get_image_uri
from sagemaker.model import Model
from sagemaker.pipeline import PipelineModel

container=sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve("xgboost", boto3.Session().region_name, "0.90-1")
print(container)

model_name = 'some_model_123'
model_location= "s3://somebucket/somemodelpath/someversion/model.tar.gz"

env = {
    'SAGEMAKER_REQUIREMENTS': 'requirements.txt',
    'SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM': 'inference.py',
    'SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY' : model_location
    }

model= Model(
    model_data=model_location, 
    image_uri =container,
    env = env
)

endpoint_name = model_name

pipeline_model = PipelineModel(name=model_name,
                               role=role,
                               models=[
                                    model
                               ])

pm = pipeline_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge", endpoint_name=endpoint_name)
```

### References

Here is a reference of a bring your own model which helped me a bunch.
https://medium.com/geekculture/84af8989d065

Here is a reference to a similar question that I posted while struggling with as well.
[How to handle custom transformation/ inference and requirements in sagemaker endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70311093/how-to-handle-custom-transformation-inference-and-requirements-in-sagemaker-end)